# Is it bad practice to use constant variables with global scope in C++?

Tags: c++

So I was reading section 3.2 (One definition rule section) in the [latest working draft of the C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) and came across this:

> Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline
>   function or variable that is odr-used in that program; no diagnostic
>   required.

This struck me as strange with regard to the *variable* part, because if a header file has a global constant variable and function like so:

```
const int k = 10;

int foo(const int &i) {
    return 0;
}
```

What if you mistakenly call `foo(k)`? It seems like this would result in UB because `k` has internal linkage (i.e. every translation unit would have its own definition of `k`, so there wouldnt be *exactly one definition ... in that program*). So basically if you have any `const` variable with global scope you'd have to remember not to call any functions which take its reference or address.

Comment: Currently the latest working draft is [N4527](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4527.pdf).

Answer (score 9):

The one definition rule in the standard is not "appear" only once, but that they have only a single definition. E.g. if the `const` were in a header file, it could appear in multiple translation units, yet they would all have the same single definition. As an aside, the linker could then fold them all into a single location (if a location is even required).

> What if you mistakenly call `foo(k)`? It seems like this would result in UB...

There would be no undefined behavior here. The internal linkage is fine, it is `const` and there is only a single definition of it.

This (the `const int i = 1234;`) has a general use case for program wide constant values, e.g. `const double pi = 3.1415`, `const std::size_t answer = 42;` etc.

On a side note, you have specifically asked about the global variables, but placing constants and the like into namespaces are always a good way to avoid name clashes etc.

Comment: Can you check the beginning of section 2.2 in [this article](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/n4147.pdf)? This describes my concerns. The relevant quote is: *"This function violates the ODR ([basic.def.odr] §3.2/6 ) twice because neither of the constructor 2
arguments receives an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion. They are therefore passed by address, but the
address depends on the TU because const (and constexpr) implies internal linkage."*

Comment: There is another paper [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4424.pdf) that proposes an alternative to the "hole" in the language you present. A key quote from your paper is "There is no way to share a compile-time constant between TUs unless it is scalar and every use is discarded or undergoes lvalue-to-rvalue conversion. This is a major hole in the language." The issue here is to that the authors want a way of defining a single instance of an object (non-scalar) for the program (instead of one for each TU) without it being `extern` - akin to the `inline` function.

Answer (score 3):

You're close, but not quite. The bad practice here is declaring global variables **outside of a namespace**.

```
namespace jucestain {
    const int k = 10;

    int foo(const int &i) {
        return 0;
    }
} // end namespace jucestain
```

Once you put it in a namespace, `foo(k)` will only resolve to `foo(10)` if you have `using namespace jucestain;` at the top of your file. Otherwise you'd have to write `jucestain::foo(jucestain::k)`, which is pretty hard to do by accident.

And even without a namespace, there's no undefined behavior because `k` still only has one definition per translation unit, and it's the translation units that matter (otherwise the header file containing `k` wouldn't have to be "included in multiple places" to begin with).

Comment: *there's no undefined behavior because k still only has one definition per translation unit*. The quote from the standard states: *that is odr-used in that **program***. I actually found a paper that mentions this [here](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/n4147.pdf) on section 2.2 page 2. The relevent quote is *"This function violates the ODR ([basic.def.odr] §3.2/6 ) twice because neither of the constructor 2
arguments receives an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion. They are therefore passed by address, but the
address depends on the TU because const (and constexpr) implies internal linkage."*

Comment: @jucestain: The trick is that each `k` in the different translation units is considered to be a distinct variable. They just happen to have the same name. This is what it means for a variable/function to have internal linkage.